# OSVERSIONINFOW.dwBuildNumber does not return the complete build number of Windows 10

Tags: windows, operating-system, windows-10, version, build-numbers

The build number of my Windows 10 is `18363.900`, as shown in the below picture.

[image: About Windows - OS Build]
I tried `RtlGetVersion(PRTL_OSVERSIONINFOW)`, but `OSVERSIONINFOW.dwBuildNumber` only returns `18363`.

Why doesn't `RtlGetVersion`  return the complete build number? How can I get the complete *OS Build number* of Windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This version is not returned by dwBuildNumber, what you want is called UBR can be read from a DWORD from registry:

[image]

This number shows the patchlevel. My 329 shows I have this [patch installed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4557957)